# Error for document field with set of enums for findAllBy method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Srping boot, MongoDB, kotlin. I have a document:

```
@Document(collection = "car")
class Car @JvmOverloads constructor(

        @Id
        var id: String? = null,

        @Field("colorId")
        var colorId: String? = null,

        @Field("parts")
        var parts: Set<Part>? = null
) {

    enum class Part {
        SCREW, CLUTCH, TIRE
    }
}
```

This is the repository with the method that "generates" an error:

```
interface CarRepository : MongoRepository<Car, String>{

    fun findAllByColorId(colorId: String): List<Car>
}
```

When I run it, I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR 7752 [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.foo.bar.Car$Part using constructor fun <init>(): com.foo.bar.Car.Part with arguments null,null] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of provided arguments should be less of equals than number of constructor parameters
```

I am totally new to kotlin (and mongo actually).

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which version of Spring Data MongoDB and Kotlin are you using? Or better: Please provide a project that is able to reproduce the issue. Also, please do not truncate stack traces.